# twitter python code to execute only limited number of tweets and term

Tags: python-3.x

I am running below code to get limited number of tweets but the code keeps failing.

```
# Create the api endpoint

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# Mention the maximum number of tweets that you want to be extracted.

maximum_number_of_tweets_to_be_extracted = \
int(input('10- '))

# Mention the hashtag that you want to look out for

hashtag = input('Roger- ')

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#' + hashtag,
rpp=100).items(maximum_number_of_tweets_to_be_extracted):
    with open('tweets_with_hashtag_' + hashtag + '.txt', 'a') as \
the_file:
the_file.write(str(tweet.text.encode('utf-8')) + '\n')

print ('Extracted ' + str(maximum_number_of_tweets_to_be_extracted) \
+ ' tweets with hashtag #' + hashtag)
```

Removing the file syntax and I think that where the problem is

Comment: Whats is the error output that you got ?

Comment: I got it working

Comment: # create list to append tweets to
tweets = []

# append all tweet data to list
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#napawine",count=100
                       ).items():
    tweets.append(tweet)

# convert 'tweets' list to pandas.DataFrame
tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(vars(tweets[i]) for i in range(len(tweets)))

# define file path (string) to save csv file to
FILE_PATH = 'resultsrm.json'

# use pandas to save dataframe to csv
tweets_df.to_csv(FILE_PATH)

Comment: but now the issue is output is coming in as json file , even if I open up it as csv it is having lot of spaces between each tweet

Comment: sorry I meant  csv is coming up but with spaces in between

Comment: Thanks all I figured the issue , I just have to convert to json file in order to use some fields